# DialogContext.continueDialog() is not working

Tags: botframework

I am storing the dialog state in my DB and when I get the response from the user I am trying to reinitiate the dialog.
But the `DialogContext.continueDialog()` is always returning empty.

I am storing the dialogStack using the below code.

```
dialogStack = await dialogContext.dialogs.dialogState.get(turnContext);
```

then I am storing this dialogStack in db.

then I am retrieving the dialogStack from db and then setting the dialogStack using the below code.

```
await dialogContext.dialogs.dialogState.set(turnContext, dialogStack);
```

after this i call

```
await dialogContext.continueDialog();
```

but this is always giving me empty.

Any ideas why? and solutions?

Comment: What db are you using? [If Cosmos, are you using a PartitionKey](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5467)? Which part is "always giving [you] empty"?

Comment: I am using AWS DynamoDB, and this works when I test this locally with the bot emulator, however when I move this to AWS Lambda it does not work.

Comment: I haven't used a bot in Lambda before, but I don't believe that's the problem. You should be creating dialogState [like this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/05.multi-turn-prompt/bots/dialogBot.js#L22) and saving it after each turn [like this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/05.multi-turn-prompt/bots/dialogBot.js#L35). Is there a reason you're doing it a different way? I could help debug if you can share a link to your repo.

Comment: Did changing how you use dialog state work? Please post code if you're still running into issues.

Comment: I can create the bot using the memory however the lambda is stateless meaning the whole memory is gone after the response is sent to the client and i have to store the end state of the dialog and then pick up based on the conversation when it comes back.  So I have to store that and retrieve it when the call is made from the same client / conversation id . In the normal application it is possible because memory is alive due to http appliacation running on a server, however here (lambda) it is not as every request span a new http server.

Comment: I see. As you can get it working locally, the issue seems to be with your Lambda setup. I don't see much about converting a resitfy app (like botframework bots) to lambda, but I do see a lot with express. You may need to convert it to express first, then [convert it to lambda](https://dev.to/brightdevs/how-to-convert-an-express-app-to-aws-lambda--44gc). I'd love to help, but without code to debug, it's very difficult. You can email it to me if you'd like. vDASHmicricATmicrosoftDOTcom -- replace all-caps with appropriate character.

Comment: I have added the express and have already implemented the bot it works with out any issue, i am able to send responses to the client where it does not involve dialogs. My specific problem is that when I assign the previous dialog state and try to continue the dialog it does not. I will send you the code.

Comment: Sounds good. FYI: I have not seen an email from you, yet. My email address is in my profile, if that helps.

Comment: Hi mdrichardson, i was able to find the issue and fixed it.